# Remove unnecessary space between li elements in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have an unordered list for horizontal navigation

The **code** is something like this

```
   <ul class="headul">
      <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="Images/2_03.jpg"/></a></li>
       <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="Images/2_04.jpg"/></a></li>
       <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="Images/2_05.jpg"/></a></li>
       <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="Images/2_06.jpg"/></a></li>
       <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="Images/2_07.jpg"/></a></li>
       <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="Images/2_08.jpg"/></a></li>
   <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="Images/2_09.jpg"/></a></li>
   </ul>
```

**css**

```
     .headul {
        display:block;
        padding:0px
            }

      .headli {
        list-style:none;
        display:block;
        letter-spacing:0;
        float:left;
        border:0px;
            }

      .headli a {float:left;
            display:block; 
            letter-spacing:0;
            float:left;
            border:0;
            }
```

Ive tried float:left, display:inline, display:block, display:inline-block, etc,

I also tried removing the spaces between the html  li elements. ( i.e put all the li elements on the same line in html code)

I also tried letter-spacing:0, font-size:0 for ul , li as well as li a

it looks great on chrome and mozilla but in IE there's a little space between all the li element.. as if IE is giving them a margin of a couple px or something... moreover it's happening on IE9.. (i use IE tester to test on earlier versions of IE but today for some reason it keeps crashing when testing IE7)

Comment: Try adding margin:0; to li elements.

Comment: done that as well nothing seems to work...

Comment: Sounds very odd... I wonder if its the list item marker that's doing it?

Comment: @TDsouza I just tried your code in JSFiddle and I saw no spaces in IE9.

Comment: Like @JonathanSampson said, it seems to be working fine [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/T4WzH/). Could you provide a JSFiddle with your problem?

Comment: then i think it's got something to do with the images(the only thing not included in the jsfiddle)

Comment: yes it was the image... changed the border of each image to 0 and now it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new css for images

```
.headli a img
 {
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot this worked.. I did try the same thing after @gushiken has suggested it.. guess I made some errors that time...

Comment: @TDsouza looks like you might want to apply some CSS reset rules (google for it, there are about 3 commonly used ones). CSS reset rules are used to create a common, plain look for all elements in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no other style rules affecting any of the ul's child elements. IE9 cannot cause such behaviour by default so I suspect it's some css that's affecting how these li,a,img elements look.

Images in IE sometimes have borders - try setting them to `border: 0 none;`.

If your list items are inline then the spaces between the html tags can push them apart.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the additional space comes from the li element? I made the experience, that images sometimes cause strange 1px gaps if they are not "display:block"...

Try to set "display:block" on the image inside the LI. That may work :)

Comment: just gave it a try... went ahead and set the margin and padding to 0 as well.... still no effect...

Comment: just fixed it... you were right.. img was the culprit.. changed the border to 0.. and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Added css for img

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
.headul {
        display:block;
        padding:0px;
        border:0px;
        margin:0px;
        }

      .headli {
        list-style:none;
        display:block;
        letter-spacing:0;
        float:left;
        margin:0px;
        border:0px;
        padding:0px;
        }

      .headli a {
        float:left;
        display:block; 
        letter-spacing:0;
        float:left;
        margin:0px;
        border:0px;
        padding:0px;
        }

      .headli a img{
        float:left;
        display:block; 
        letter-spacing:0;
        float:left;
        margin:0px;
        border:0px;
        padding:0px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="headul">
      <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="../images/user.png"/></a></li>
      <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="../images/user.png"/></a></li>
      <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="../images/user.png"/></a></li>
      <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="../images/user.png"/></a></li>
      <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="../images/user.png"/></a></li>
      <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="../images/user.png"/></a></li>
      <li class="headli"><a href="#"><img src="../images/user.png"/></a></li>
   </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**Before change**

[image]

**After change**

[image]